# Second form loads first, and main form is not visible until first form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I need the main form to load first, and the second form to load as a dialog on top of it. When I try the following, the proFileDialog loads, the mnuForm stays hidden until I close proFileDialog I can tie it to a timer, but for the sake of learning c#, why does it load out of order, and how do I make it behave appropriately?

```
private void mnuForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    using (Form proFileDialog = new Form())
    {
        proFileDialog.Text = "Some new form";
        proFileDialog.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        proFileDialog.Opacity = 100;
        proFileDialog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        // form.Controls.Add(...);
        proFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears according to the MSDN documentation on the [Order of Events in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx) that a control is not made visible until after the `Load` event.

Try subscribing to the [`Shown` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) on your `mnuForm` and place your code in there. 
This is the last event that runs when `mnuForm` starts up, and `mnuForm` should already be visible.

Also, your `profileDialog` form will only display once:

> The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed; subsequently minimizing, maximizing, restoring, hiding, showing, or invalidating and repainting will not raise this event.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx), the FormLoad event occurs before the form is displayed. Since you're displaying the second form as a dialog, it will halt at that line before the FormLoad event is finished.
What you can do is create a function in the main form that will be called to show the modal dialog:

```
public void ShowProfileDialog()
{
    Form proFileDialog = new Form();
    profileDialog.ShowDialog()
}
```

When calling your main form:

```
mnuForm mainform = new mnuForm();
mnuForm.Show();
mnuForm.ShowProfileDialog();
```

By this way, the main form has loaded completely so you can show the other form.

Comment: I can't find an event triggered once the form is rendered, so what is the right way to get the order right?